# Overriding default value of instance var

Tags: overriding, swift, default-value, instance-variables, subclassing

Given class `Obj`,

```
class Obj: NSObject {
    var x = "x"
}
```

and its subclass, `Obj1`, how do you change the default value of `var x`?

Simply setting a new value would make the most sense, but it seems to error out...

```
class Obj1: Obj {
    var x = "y"
}
```

> ❗️ Cannot override with a stored property 'x'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define an `init()` method as:

```
init () {
  super.init()
  x = "y"
}
```

You'll want any other initializers in `Obj1` to invoke this as `self.init()`.  The Apple documentation has a long discussion on *designated initializers* and inheritance vis-a-vis initializers.

Answer (score 9):

In most cases, injecting these values via `init` is the preferred way.

For example:

```
class Foo
{
    var x : String

    convenience init()
    {
        self.init(x: "x")  // 'x' by default
    }

    init(x: String)
    {
        self.x = x
    }
}

class Bar : Foo
{
    convenience init()
    {
        self.init(x: "y")   // now 'y' by default
    }

    init(x: String)
    {
        super.init(x: x)
    }
}
```

However, there are some cases where you want to override a computed property or perhaps something that is not exactly initialized.

In this case, you can use the `override var` syntax:

```
override var x : String
{
    get { return super.x }      // get super.x value
    set { super.x = newValue }  // set super.x value
}
```

The above code does not change the behavior, but illustrates the syntax that would allow you to do so.

Answer (score 6):

This question has been marked answered, but there is also the safe-in-Swift [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) by way of delegation to a computed property:

```
class Foo {
    lazy var x : String = self.defaultX
    var defaultX:String { return "foo" }
}

class Bar : Foo {
    override var defaultX:String { return "bar" }
}


println(Foo().x) // foo
println(Bar().x) // bar
```

By safer, I am referring to Swift's enforcement of the initialization sequence that prevents problems with "virtual" calls into a not-yet constructed sub class (ie, having a base class call a virtual method that is implemented in a sub class, but before that subclass has finished initializing).  This was a danger in C++, for example.

Comment: Awesome! This really saved me a lot of time :-)

Answer (score 1):

In swift 3 I've found that chrisco's solution doesn't work anymore,
But it works if you declare the variable in the base class with `private(set)`.

```
class Parent {
    private(set) var name = "Dad"
}

class Child: Parent {
    override var name: String { return "Son" }
}
```